# Google Drive API - share(copy) my file automatically to user drive account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

the scenario is like this. I have a file in Google Drive, then share it to public, but not the direct link to my file. see sample here h*ttps://ganool.ag/steve-jobs-2015-bluray-720p-ganool-ag/ | scroll down and find link h*ttps://file.rocks/file/jBH0tM97Ne (ignore the pirate movie in the link, it's just sample). When you click the link, the file will be copied to your drive account, save in a folder called File.rocks, than a subfolder with random name.

my question is, what API command used in that script? just the concept, not the complete script.

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior shown in that website is similar to the [Save to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive) button which allows the user to save files to their Drive account from an arbitrary URL via their browser.

> The technology used to upload files is similar to that used by the Google Drive web user interface. The file is downloaded to the user's browser in parts and uploaded to Google Drive as data is received.

Answer (score 0):

- Authorize your app to get `code`
- exchange `code` for `token`
- create `client-folder-id` if not exist
- then use `copy`

for example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<your-file-id>/copy
Authorization: Bearer token...xxxxxx
{
 "parents": [
  "<client-folder-id>"
 ]
}
```